# Multiplying block matrices

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix, linear-algebra, functional-style

I have a 2*8 matrix A, and a 2*8*2 matrix B. So B[[1]] and B[[2]] are both 8*2 matrices.
I need a neat way to multiply A by B so that the first list in the result is A.B[[1]] and       the second list is A.B[[2]].$$\textbf{A}.\begin{bmatrix}\textbf{B}_1\\\textbf{B}_2\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}\textbf{A}.\textbf{B}_1\\\textbf{A}.\textbf{B}_2\end{bmatrix}$$ 
Where $\textbf{A,B}$ are all compatible matrices.
In other words, I want to multiply two partitioned matrices and get the result in the partitioned form also.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
a = RandomReal[{0, 1}, {2, 8}];
b = RandomReal[{0, 1}, {2, 8, 2}];

a.# & /@ b
```

> {{{2.58906, 3.35618}, {2.5578, 3.12812}}, {{1.3762, 
>          2.87723}, {1.56668, 3.04675}}}

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thanks alot.

Answer (score 5):

You can also use

```
(a.b\[Transpose])\[Transpose]
```

or, equivalently,

```
Transpose[a.Transpose[b]]
```

to get the same result.

```
a = RandomReal[{0, 1}, {2, 8}];
b = RandomReal[{0, 1}, {2, 8, 2}];
c = a.# & /@ b;  (* from Sjoerd's answer *)

(a.b\[Transpose])\[Transpose] == c
(* True *)
```

Answer (score 3):

Another way:

```
a = RandomReal[{0, 1}, {2, 8}];
b = RandomReal[{0, 1}, {2, 8, 2}];

m = First@Outer[Dot, {a}, b, 1];
```

Compare with Sjoerd's:

```
s = a.# & /@ b;  (* Sjoerd's *)
s == m
(*  True  *)
```